# Is it safe using `$` as an identifier in C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, special-characters, identifier

Is it safe to use `$` character as part of identifier in C/C++?
Like this,

```
int $a = 10;
struct $b;
class $c;

void $d();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. The C standard only guarantees the use of uppercase and lowercase English letters, digits, `_`, and Unicode codepoints specified using `\u (hex-quad)` or `\U (hex-quad) (hex-quad)` (with a few exceptions). Specific compilers may allow other characters as an extension; however this is highly nonportable. (ISO/IEC 9899:1999 (E) 6.4.2.1, 6.4.3) Further note that the Unicode codepoint method is basically useless in identifiers, even though it is, strictly speaking, permitted (in C99), as it still shows up as a literal `\uXXXX` in your editor.

Comment: Just curious, is this part about the guarantee also true in C++?

Comment: @Mehrdad, the C++98 standard specifies essentially the same definition, except that implementation-defined characters and unicode codepoints are not allowed - so, effectively, it's even more restrictive

Answer (score 5):

No; it is a non-standard extension in some compilers.

Answer (score 1):

This is not standard and only Microsoft Visual Studio (that I know of) even allows the '$' character in identifiers.

So if you ever want your code to be portable (or readable to others), I'd say no.

Comment: gcc (activated or not by default depending on the platform), Digital C compiler for the VMS (on VMS it is needed to access system libraries).